# Repeated column in mapping for entity: entity.LaAssociateGridEntity column: AssociateId (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have got two different rest endpoints to insert data into DB where:

- /api1 will insert data into **Table1** and **Table3**
- where as /api2 will insert data into Table **Table1** and **Table3** but facing this error while inserting the data into db.

*I have got three tables: **Table1**, **Table2**, **Table3***

- Table1 and Table3's association is  @OneToMany
- Table2 and Table3's association is **ALSO** @OneToMany

The solution that I am getting is: (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false") but this will prevent the insertion and updating of the data into database for these columns.

How do I use these
Sharing snippet of the code block where I'm facing the issue. Please let me know if you want me to share the whole code

```
@Data @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true) @Entity @Table(name = "[dbo].[LAInstructions]")
public class LaInstructionsEntity extends AuditableFields<Long> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private Long id;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @**OneToMany**(mappedBy = "laInstructionsEntity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<LaAssociateGridEntity> laAssociateGridEntities;

    @Column(name = "Active")
    private Boolean active;

}
```

---

**Table 2:**

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "[dbo].[LALegalCreditCheck]")
public class LALegalCreditCheckEntity extends AuditableFields<Long> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private Long id;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @**OneToMany**(mappedBy = "laLegalCreditCheckEntity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = LaAssociateGridEntity.class)
    List<LaAssociateGridEntity> laAssociateGridEntities;

    @Column(name = "Active")
    Boolean active;

}
```

---

**Table 3:**

```
@Data @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true) @Entity @Table(name = "[dbo].[LAAssociateGrid]")
public class LaAssociateGridEntity extends AuditableFields<Long> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "Active")
    private Boolean active;

    @JsonBackReference
    @**ManyToOne**(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "AssociateId", referencedColumnName = "Id")
    private LaInstructionsEntity laInstructionsEntity;

    @**ManyToOne**(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "AssociateId", referencedColumnName = "Id")
    private LALegalCreditCheckEntity laLegalCreditCheckEntity;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error says that in `LaAssociateGridEntity` , both `laInstructionsEntity` and `laLegalCreditCheckEntity` fields are also mapped to the same column (i.e. `AssociateId`) , so Hibernate does not know which fields should it consider when mapping this column.

I believe there is a typo in one of them. `LaInstructionsEntity` and `LALegalCreditCheckEntity` are different entities. And without another discriminator column , how can you differentiate for the same `AssociateId` in `LaAssociateGridEntity` , its parent is `LaInstructionsEntity` or `LALegalCreditCheckEntity` ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, do you mean to say that Table1 and Table2 can not have @ManyToOne relationship with same column from Table3?

Comment: No. I mean in Table3 , you define the same column that are referenced to Table1 and Table2 , so how to determine when should this column in Table3 reference Table1 and when should it reference to Table2 ?